# Cannot get an email with Microsoft Graph API due to encoding conversion failure on Microsoft side

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-mail

Trying to get with Microsoft Graph API an email but get an error from Microsoft side:

> Request: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/user_id/messages/message_id;
> Request body size: 0; ReplyBodyError: { ErrorCode:
> "ErrorInternalServerError", ErrorMessage: "An internal server error
> occurred. The operation failed.,
> Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Globalization.Iso2022Jp.DecodeJisX0208_1983ToCp932.GetNextRun
> output length 240 does not match ConvertToCp932 length 239" }

I am not sure, is it possible or not provide such email since it's confidential email from our customer. It's not a single case - we have 7 emails with the same error.

So I have several questions:

1. What is the reason of the problem?
2. Is it now possible to download such emails with Microsoft Graph API? With EWS API?
3. Is it known issue? If yes - is there any estimations for fix?

Thank you.